# How to use a textform instead of editable div with this code

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

**EDIT:** I was able to get the code below working thanks to a some help in the comments but it does it to everything instead of the highlighted text.

```js
$(".boldtrigger").click(function() {$(".text").toggleClass("bold");});
$(".italictrigger").click(function() {$(".text").toggleClass("italic");});
$(".underlinetrigger").click(function() {$(".text").toggleClass("underline");});
```

```css
.bold { font-weight: bold;}
.italic {font-style: italic;}
.underline {text-decoration: underline;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" class="boldtrigger">Bold</a> <a href="#" class="italictrigger">italic</a> <a href="#" class="underlinetrigger">underline</a>
<textarea class="text">Here is the text.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to make this div into a textarea box instead? It works fine as of current but it won't work for my needs when submitting a form. How to get this to work?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {$('#jBold').click(function() {document.execCommand('bold');}).find('#fake_textarea').removeAttr('disabled').trigger('focus');});
$(document).ready(function() {$('#jUnderline').click(function() {document.execCommand('underline');}).find('#fake_textarea').removeAttr('disabled').trigger('focus');});
$(document).ready(function() {$('#jNewline').click(function() {document.execCommand('insertHtml', false, '<br>');}).find('#fake_textarea').removeAttr('disabled').trigger('focus');})
```

```css
        #fake_textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 200px;
}

button {
  font-weigth: bold;
}
span {display: table;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="jBold" type="button"><b>B</b></button> <button id="jUnderline" type="button"><u>U</u></button> <button id="jNewline" type="button">New Line</button>
<div id='fake_textarea' contenteditable='true'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can we change the in the HTML?

Comment: @Aman what do you mean?

Comment: In the HTML `<div id='fake_textarea' contenteditable='true'></div>` is written, can't we change it to `<textarea></textarea>`

Comment: I tried that, it wouldn't switch over the way you think it does. Maybe im doing something wrong?..

Comment: Or Maybe you are doing right, you just neet to apply all conditions or class to textarea that were written for contenteditable div.

Comment: I tried replacing the div with a textarea and kept all the same id's but no luck :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your help but I actually came across an old post [On this old BBcode page](https://www.codingforums.com/javascript-programming/134113-how-do-i-make-bold-italic-underline-command.html) about how to solve this and the code stays when sent through a form and the results show the html. You can also add a **NextLine** button if you mess around with the code, very helpful. P.S.: The javascript goes in the header for this one.

```js
function formatText(el,tag){
var selectedText=document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd);
var newText='<'+tag+'>'+selectedText+'</'+tag+'>';
if(document.selection){//IE
document.selection.createRange().text=newText;
}
else{//Moz
el.value=el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart)+newText+el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd,el.value.length);
}
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
<textarea name="myTextarea" rows = "12" cols = "50">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</textarea><br>
<input type="button" value="Bold" onclick="formatText (myTextarea,'b');" />
<input type="button" value="Italic" onclick="formatText (myTextarea,'i');" />
<input type="button" value="Underline" onclick="formatText (myTextarea,'u');" />
</form>
```